# Eclipse - res location

Tags: android, eclipse

Is it possible to change the location of the res folder so it's not in the Eclipse project?

I know I can link the src folder of the project to another location, but can I do the same for the res folder.

I had some issues when I included the Eclipse project into svn, so I would like to keep them separate like I do on any Flash/Flex builder project.

Comment: The best way is to simply fix you SVN issues and leave the android project you are working on as it is meant to be.

Comment: Why downvote this question? It's perfectly valid, and it can be a problem in more situations, not necessarily SVN-related. Explain when you downvote.

Comment: Thanks for that Felix. Reno wasn't happy with the grammar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think that would make sense, as they are needed at the time your project is built, and when Eclipse refers to resources they have.

Don't put them anywhere else than its current location.

Comment: Cheers WarrenFaith and Sheikh.